# References are enclosed in square bracket in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am using book class to write my thesis, for the citation I am using author-year citation I get for example:

Arasaratnam, I., Haykin, S. : Cubature Kalman filters. IEEE Trans. Autom. Control. 54, 1254–1269 (2011)

but I want the following:

[Arasaratnam et Haykin 2011] I. Arasaratnam, S. Haykin, Cubature Kalman filters. IEEE Trans. Autom. Control. 54, 1254–1269 (2011)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red, citecolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\setcitestyle{square,aysep={},yysep={,}} 

\begin{document}

First citation \citep{Winter2017}, second citation \citep{Arasaratnam2009}, third citation \citep{Cheng2016}


\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Winter et coll}{2017}]{Winter2017} F. Winter, C. Bludszuweit-Philipp, O. Wolkenhauer, Mathematical analysis of the influence of brain metabolism on the BOLD signal in Alzheimer's disease. J. Cereb. Blood Flow Metab. 38 (2). 304--316. (2017).

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Arasaratnam et Haykin}{2009}]{Arasaratnam2009} I. Arasaratnam, S. Haykin, Cubature Kalman filters. IEEE Trans. Autom. Control. 54, 1254--1269 (2011)

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Cheng et He}{2016}]{Cheng2016}
Y. Cheng, W. He, Establishment of the intracranial hemodynamic model based on contrast medium and clinical applications. Medicine. 95 (49). e5550. (2016)

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324541/35864

Answer (score 2):

Since the bibliography appears to be hand-built, you need repeat the `[Arasaratnam et Haykin 2011]`-type element explicitly. E.g., you should change

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Arasaratnam et Haykin}{2009}]{Arasaratnam2009}
I. Arasaratnam, S. Haykin, Cubature Kalman filters. IEEE Trans. Autom. Control.
54, 1254--1269 (2011)
```

to

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Arasaratnam et Haykin}{2009}]{Arasaratnam2009}
[Arasaratnam et Haykin 2009]
I. Arasaratnam, S. Haykin, Cubature Kalman filters. IEEE Trans. Autom. Control.
54, 1254--1269 (2011)
```